# Roots of the reduction of $x^p - (p-1)x^{p-1}-x+(p-1)^p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ modulo $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $$g(x) = x^p - (p-1)x^{p-1}-x+(p-1)^p \in \mathbb{Z}[x].$$

How does one prove that the reduction of $g(x)$ modulo $p$ has exactly one root of multiplicity $2$ and the other roots are all simple?

Applying Fermat Little Theorem I find that the reduction is $$(x+1)(x^{p-1}-1) = (x+1)^2(x-1)(x^{p-3} + \dots + 1),$$ where we have the term $(x^{p-3} + \dots + 1)$ if $p > 2$. Is this correct? How do I go on from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your polynomial in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ as
$$g_p(x)=(x+1)(x^{p-1}-1) \in \mathbb Z_p[x].$$
So you have that $-1$ is a root of the first factor. For computing the roots of the second factor observe that, by Fermat Little Theorem, every element of $\mathbb Z_p^*:=\mathbb Z_p\smallsetminus\{0\}$ is a root of it. So you have $p-1$ roots for a polynomial of degree $p-1$. Hence 
$$x^{p-1}-1=\prod_{a\in\mathbb Z_p^*}(x-a),$$
and
$$g_p(x)=(x+1)\prod_{a\in\mathbb Z_p^*}(x-a).$$
At this point it should be clear that $-1$ is a root of multiplicity $2$, while the other roots are simple.

Comment: Very good point. Thanks.